# search bug "[tag1] -[tag2]" with unanswered filter

Tags: bug, search

If I perform a search of `"[tag1] -[tag2]"` then I get the expected behaviour of having anything with `[tag1]` and no `[tag2]` [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+-jquery). However, if I then click on the `unanswered` button, I am presented with a blank page stating that there are 0 results found as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/javascript+-jquery). I do not understand this behaviour, as I can clearly see that there are several unanswered questions in the original search.

This bug can be bypassed by using the advanced search function`"[tag1] and -[tag2] answers:0 closed:no"` ([e.g. this](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D%20and%20-%5Bjquery%5D%20answers%3A0%20closed%3Ano)) but this is slightly different from the unanswered button as this will exclude any questions with an answer with score 0.

I believe this to be a bug, but maybe I am using something incorrectly?